# Is the Rails for Zombies course usefull?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-for-zombies

Is the [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) course on [CodeSchool](http://www.codeschool.com/) useful?

I am thinking weather it is worth my time, taking it and if it really provides useful resources?

I haven't done any other [CodeSchool](http://www.codeschool.com/) courses till now. What do you think about the platform? Is it worth paying for other payed courses?

Are there any high quality free online web development courses?

Comment: I've done it and I disliked it very much. I suggest you get a book. That course is crap

Comment: This question is inapropriate here. It asks for opinion and discussion, and those types of questions are specifically mentioned in the [FAQ](http:///stackoverflow.com/faq) as being a poor fit for the design of StackOverflow. Voting to close as not constructive for those reasons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's meant just to get you excited with the awesome Rails features :)
It will give you the very basics of Ruby and Rails and nothing more.

Actually the framework is much more complicated and time consuming. If you really would like to work with it, that course might be a showcase of some of it's best features.
Anyway it's worth checking it out if you are Ruby or Rails beginner.

Answer (score 7):

The best thing about the current ruby/rails eco-system is there are a multitude of learning  resource options out there, and it should't be too hard for anyone to find the ones suited to their needs/aptitude/...

Try out the Rails For Zombies course and a few other CodeSchool courses for free, and decide for yourself if you like them, and want to go for the paid courses.

I am partial to [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) as the best free resource to learn web development with Rails. The book available for free online. It provides the best introduction to all the concepts & tools involved while working with ruby/rails to build web applications.

[RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/) - both the free version & the premium version - would be my next recommendation in building up skills.

Take a look at the answers for [Best online (free) resources for learning Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993855/best-online-free-resources-for-learning-ruby-on-rails) to learn about more alternatives, and pick what works for you.

Quite a few people in the ruby community rave about [Why's poignant guide to ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/book/chapter-1.html) as one of the best resources to learn ruby, but it didn't work for me. After spending a little time on it, I moved on to [Learn to program](http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/) which turned out to be a perfect fit for my style :-)